# the method toseq() is ambiguous for the type Buffer<Column>

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm getting bellow compile error in return statement

```
List<Column> colList= .....;
return dataset.select(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(colList).toSeq());
```

error:

```
the method toSeq() is ambiguous for the type Buffer<Column>
```

Not able to fix this error. any suggestion ?

Comment: a cheap fix could be to cast `JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(colList)` to a class you know that is returned. Can you provide more code? an 'ambiguous' warning from the compiler has in most cases an underlying problem you should fix (e.g. rename the `toSeq` method so that its not ambiguous?).

Comment: You can try with toList() instead of toSeq()